# Realm Different Schema Version Error

Tags: android, realm, version

I use Realm in Android and it's useful. But gets these errors sometimes when app start:

**Error-1:**

```
Exception io.realm.exceptions.RealmFileException: Too many open files () (/data/data/[REDACTED_DOMAIN_NAME]/files/e_app.realm) in /home/cc/repo/realm/release/realm/realm-library/src/main/cpp/io_realm_internal_SharedRealm.cpp line 91
io.realm.internal.SharedRealm.nativeGetSharedRealm (SharedRealm.java)
io.realm.internal.SharedRealm.<init> (SharedRealm.java:180)
io.realm.internal.SharedRealm.getInstance (SharedRealm.java:227)
io.realm.BaseRealm.<init> (BaseRealm.java:124)
io.realm.BaseRealm.<init> (BaseRealm.java:93)
io.realm.Realm.<init> (Realm.java:150)
io.realm.Realm.createInstance (Realm.java:417)
io.realm.RealmCache.doCreateRealmOrGetFromCache (RealmCache.java:348)
io.realm.RealmCache.createRealmOrGetFromCache (RealmCache.java:281)
io.realm.Realm.getDefaultInstance (Realm.java:325)
com.app.android.dao.RealmEncryptionHelper.createEncryptedRealm (RealmEncryptionHelper.java:47)
com.app.android.dao.RealmController.getRealm (RealmController.java:104)
com.app.android.dao.RealmController$1.run (RealmController.java:48)
java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:762)
```

**Error-2:**

```
Exception io.realm.exceptions.RealmError: Unrecoverable error. Too many open files in /home/cc/repo/realm/release/realm/realm-library/src/main/cpp/io_realm_internal_SharedRealm.cpp line 91
io.realm.internal.SharedRealm.nativeGetSharedRealm ()
io.realm.internal.SharedRealm.<init> ()
io.realm.internal.SharedRealm.getInstance ()
io.realm.internal.SharedRealm.getInstance ()
io.realm.ca.b ()
io.realm.ca.a ()
io.realm.by.l ()
com.app.android.dao.a.a ()
com.app.android.MyApplication.e ()
com.app.android.e.a.b ()
com.app.android.e.a$1.onMessage ()
okhttp3.internal.ws.RealWebSocket.onReadMessage ()
okhttp3.internal.ws.WebSocketReader.readMessageFrame ()
okhttp3.internal.ws.WebSocketReader.processNextFrame ()
okhttp3.internal.ws.RealWebSocket.loopReader ()
okhttp3.internal.ws.RealWebSocket$2.onResponse ()
okhttp3.RealCall$AsyncCall.execute ()
okhttp3.internal.NamedRunnable.run ()
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:818)
```

**Error-3:**

```
Exception java.lang.IllegalStateException: Realm at path '/data/data/[REDACTED_DOMAIN_NAME]/files/e_app.realm' already opened with different schema version.
io.realm.internal.SharedRealm.nativeGetSharedRealm ()
io.realm.internal.SharedRealm.<init> ()
io.realm.internal.SharedRealm.getInstance ()
io.realm.h.<init> ()
io.realm.h.<init> ()
io.realm.by.<init> ()
io.realm.by.a ()
io.realm.ca.b ()
io.realm.ca.a ()
io.realm.by.l ()
com.app.android.dao.a.a ()
com.app.android.dao.a$1.run ()
java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:818)
```

I think these errors related each other. I don't get above errors every starting. But some devices gets this errors and I think it's not about related with devices.
No changed Realm's schema version. Bu I had this error.

Comment: What Realm version is this?

Comment: Version is  4.1.1

Comment: It sounds like you are opening the Realm on about 150 threads without ever closing it.

Comment: Logs say like that but its no such thing. Because It does not happen every starting.

Comment: Do you have a `close()` for every `getInstance` (or `getDefaultInstance()`) call?

Comment: Absolutely. I use `close()` after very `getInstance()`.

Comment: Different schema version most likely means that you are trying to open the Realm with a different configuration in different places.. :O

Comment: I know. But it's realm issue. When updating app, it does not close all Realm. I don't have to close all Realm. It's job is Realm's.

Comment: Try to only create one `RealmConfiguration` and use it everywhere. It seems that you have different `RealmConfiguration` being used that they have different schema version defined.

Comment: Schema version changes sometimes so I have to create configure each changing schema version. I use same config other times.

Comment: @dralexnumber how u resolve this issue ?

Comment: yes @Erum you have to use one thread and it's resolved.